# Cannot apply patches to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, patching

I have a SQL Server 2016 instance version is SP1-GDR - 13.0.4202.2. I want to apply the Cumulative Update packages but they will not install. When you step through them, you cannot select any options to install they are all greyed out. I am trying to install CU5 - 13.0.4451.0.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running the installer with elevated permissions?  What do the bootstrap logs show?